# Syslog: What is the Configuration for Log errors using syslog in my PHP Application

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, syslog

How to Configure Syslog For my PHP Application in Windows? I have Surferd in Internet Shows Many Server need to install.

What are the Configurations Made to obtain the SysLog Using PHP?

Comment: PHP Default Function bool syslog ( int $priority , string $message )  Only Logs the Errors, warnings Shown on Windows default Event Viewer, without configuring any change in php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

```
    // open syslog, include the process ID and also send
// the log to standard error, and use a user defined
// logging mechanism
openlog("myScriptLog", LOG_PID | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL0);

// some code

if (authorized_client()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // unauthorized client!
    // log the attempt
    $access = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Unauthorized client: $access {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} ({$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']})");
}

closelog();
```

for more check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php

Comment: where i need to place "myScriptLog" File what are its configuration??